# Как получить данные из promise?

Tags: java, node.js, fetch

Можно ли получить данные в json из запроса с сервера и положить их в какую-то переменную/массив и т.д.?Я прочитал,что такое такое невозможно,но как-то не верится в это,неужели надо работать с данными сервера всегда внутри .then и их оттуда никак не вытащить?

Если это все-таки возможно,то как вытащить data во внешнюю переменную  в этом коде?

```
fetch(mainpage_url)
.then((response)=>{
return response.json();
})
.then((data)=>{
console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: @nörbörnën Извините,но там написано так же все внутри async функции

Comment: да_____________